# normalize and filtering long matrix with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I am enjoying learning about dplyr however, still can't do more than basic stuff.

Basically, I would like to normalize a data (dividing entries by the sum of rows)

```
messy <- data.frame(o1 = c(1,2,1,2),
                    o2 = c(2,3,0,1),
                    o3 = c(3,2,0,1),
                    o4 = c(1,1,4,4))
normalized.messy = messy/apply(messy,1,sum)
```

and then I would like to identify columns as such

```
apply(normalized.messy,2,sum)/sum(apply(normalized.messy,2,sum))
```

I have done something like the following

```
messy <- data.frame(samples = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"),
                o1 = c(1,2,1,2),
                o2 = c(2,3,0,1),
                o3 = c(3,2,0,1),
                o4 = c(1,1,4,4))

bb = gather(messy, otu, counts, o1:o4)
group_by(bb, otu) %>% mutate(nr = scale(count))
bb.nr = group_by(bb, otu) %>% mutate(nr = scale(count))
```

but get the following error,

```
Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I appreciate in correcting the scaling part as well as filtering

Answer (score 0):

To address the error you are getting, I suspect that it is because you named the column counts (with an s) instead of just count.

As far as your dplyr code goes, I think you have the first group by backwards. Here's my understanding of what you want. First you want to group by sample to get the proportion of OTUs per sample, then you want to group by OTUs to get the mean OTU proportion across samples:

```
messy <- data.frame(samples = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"),
            o1 = c(1,2,1,2),
            o2 = c(2,3,0,1),
            o3 = c(3,2,0,1),
            o4 = c(1,1,4,4))
bb <- gather(messy, otu, counts, o1:o4)

bb %>% group_by(samples) %>% mutate(prop = counts/sum(counts)) %>%
       group_by(otu) %>% summarize(mean(prop))
```